# Is there any provision to change the password expiration age of Azure AD users in the Azure portal Itself

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I checked the Microsoft document, they are mentioning we can change the password expiration value (default 90 days) using powershell or admin.microsoft.com portal. Is there any tab present in Azure AD itself, instead of using powershell or admin.microsoft.com for changing the password expiration value.

Answer (score 1):

•   To set the ‘Password Expiration’ value from the Azure portal itself, kindly refer to the following steps below: -

a)  Login to the Microsoft 365 admin URL: - ***https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=2072756*** and select the **‘Setup’** tab as shown below in the snapshot: -

[image: Microsoft 365 Security and setup]

b)  Select the **‘Set the passwords to never expire’** option, then *`uncheck the box next to ‘Set passwords to never expire (recommended)’ option and then in the box for ‘Number of days before passwords expire’ option, type in the number of days before you expect the passwords should expire for every user including the ‘Global Administrator’ account in your M365 tenant/Azure AD portal`* as shown below: -

[image: M365 Password expiration]

c)  **`You will have to select the number of days from 14 to 730 to set the password expiration for all accounts in M365/Azure AD`** as shown above.

•   Please note that **all the users created in Azure AD are shown in M365 portal and vice versa as Microsoft 365 is itself a manageable part of the Azure AD through its undetachable authentication and authorization mechanism interwoven through various Microsoft SaaS platforms, apps, and services**.

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/set-password-expiration-policy?view=o365-worldwide#set-password-expiration-policy***

Thus, in this way, you can **configure the ‘Password expiration’ for users in Azure AD through the Azure/M365 portal itself**.